# Adding a CMS block via setup script

Tags: admin, magento-enterprise, cms

I am working on a site that has, I believe 9 separate Magento instances, same site.

Therefore there are strict procedures surrounding any back-end data - config and even for CMS blocks.

I would like to find out how to add a CMS block via a setup script.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For this, I suggest using the `data` folder of one of your custom modules.
Let's say that the module is currently at version `1.0.4`.

Create the file `data/[module]_setup/data-upgrade-1.0.4-1.0.5.php` with the following content:

**Edit: changed file name**

```
$content = 'BLOCK CONTENT HERE';
//if you want one block for each store view, get the store collection
$stores = Mage::getModel('core/store')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('store_id', array('gt'=>0))->getAllIds();
//if you want one general block for all the store viwes, uncomment the line below
//$stores = array(0);
foreach ($stores as $store){
    $block = Mage::getModel('cms/block');
    $block->setTitle('Block title here');
    $block->setIdentifier('block_identifier_here');
    $block->setStores(array($store));
    $block->setIsActive(1);
    $block->setContent($content);
    $block->save();
}
```

After this just change the version in `config.xml` to `1.0.5` clear the cache and refresh any page.

Comment: Adding a CMS is block is hardly a bugfix so feature version must be bumped. 

Comment: Would `Mage::app()->getStores()` do the same?

Answer (score 9):

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$staticBlock = array(
                'title' => 'Test Block',
                'identifier' => 'test-block',                   
                'content' => 'Sample Test Block',
                'is_active' => 1,                   
                'stores' => array(0)
                );

Mage::getModel('cms/block')->setData($staticBlock)->save();
```

From: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-create-cms-page-static-block-programmatically/#sthash.1FYKYYhI.dpuf

Answer (score 5):

Instead of using the `sql` folder, you should put any setup scripts modifying CMS data in the `data` folder. See `app/code/core/Mage/Cms/data/cms_setup` for some good examples. These install scripts add static blocks and CMS pages.

For changing config values, use this code:

```
$installer->setConfigData(
    Mage_Page_Model_Config::XML_PATH_CMS_LAYOUTS,
    'your_value_here'
);
```

Also, [Here's a useful article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/using-magento-1-6-data-install-scripts/)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use below code in upgrade script:

```
$installer = $this;
/* @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$connection = $installer->getConnection();
/* @var $connection Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql */

$installer->startSetup();
$connection->insert($installer->getTable('cms/block'), array(
    'title'             => 'Footer Links',  
    'identifier'        => 'footer-links',
    'content'           => '<ul>\r\n<li><a href=\"{{store direct_url=\"about-magento-demo-store\"}}\">About Us</a></li>\r\n<li class=\"last\"><a href=\"{{store direct_url=\"customer-service\"}}\">Customer Service</a></li>\r\n</ul>',
    'creation_time'     => now(),
    'update_time'       => now(),
));
$connection->insert($installer->getTable('cms/block_store'), array(
    'block_id'   => $connection->lastInsertId(),
    'store_id'  => 0
));
$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: You should not add content to the database with direct SQL if it can be avoided (which is almost always).  In this case you can use the model cms/block to add data safely.

Answer (score 0):

The following code create and update static block using magento scripts

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/how-to-create-and-update-the-static-blocks-using-magento-script/

```
function createBlock($blockData) {

$block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($blockData['identifier']);
$block->setTitle($blockData['title']);
$block->setIdentifier($blockData['identifier']);
$block->setStores(array($blockData['storeId']));
$block->setIsActive($blockData['active']);
$block->setContent($blockData['content']);
$block->save();
```

}